# Building an app using a wrapper

Tags: discussion, contest

To be considered for the contest must our app use 100% self made code or can we use someones wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a third-party wrapper without penalty.  I'd even say its encouraged, as using a wrapper gives its author valuable feedback.

Comment: Ya, please use my wrapper!

Comment: Will be using the .Net Wrapper. :/

Comment: Just posted a comment on the post announcing the API asking the same question :)